# Reading CSV file with text using textread

Tags: matlab, csv

I am reading a csv file in Matlab using `textread` function and storing the values in the cells of string and float types.

```
[string1, string2, values] = textread('/path/xyz.csv', '%s %s %f', 'headerlines', 1);
```

Data has three columns. Two of them I believe are of string type and one is float.

Sample Data

```
@timestamp  host    value
March 5th 2019, 13:41:54.879    tscompute1  0.399
March 5th 2019, 13:41:54.879    tscompute1  0.599
March 5th 2019, 13:41:54.879    tscompute1  0
March 5th 2019, 13:41:54.879    tscompute1  0.2
March 5th 2019, 13:41:54.879    tscompute1  0
March 5th 2019, 13:41:54.879    tscompute1  0
March 5th 2019, 13:41:54.879    tscompute1  0
March 5th 2019, 13:41:54.879    tscompute1  0
March 5th 2019, 13:41:54.879    tscompute1  0
March 5th 2019, 13:41:54.879    tscompute1  100
March 5th 2019, 13:41:54.879    tscompute1  0.4
```

There is not execution error. But the read values are not as expected. Please find the sample output below.

Values stored in string1 looks like as follows

```
'"March'
','
'"March'
','
'"March'
','
'"March'
','
```

Values stored in string2 looks like as follows

```
'5th'
'13:41:54.879",tscompute1,0.399'
'5th'
'13:41:54.879",tscompute1,0.599'
'5th'
'13:41:54.879",tscompute1,0'
'5th'
'13:41:54.879",tscompute1,0.2'
```

Values stored in values looks like as follows

```
2019
0
2019
0
2019
0
2019
0
```

Comment: Looking at the [textread doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textread.html), you can specify a delimiter. From the image of your data, I would guess, that the columns are separated by tab? So, try setting the delimiter option to tab `\t`. As an addition: The help suggests to use `textscan` instead of `textread`.

Comment: Please share your text file as text and not an image.

Comment: Edit your question and include a sample in your question, do not provide a link to an external website.

Comment: You can't attach a text or csv file with the question.

Comment: I am not talking about attaching a file. Just copy the first few lines of the text file and add them to your question.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Please find the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Your text seems to have inconsistent delimiters, the date is separated from the time by a comma, while the time, the name "tscompute1" and the number are separated by white-spaces.

The simplest is to read every line as six elements each separated by white-spaces with five of them being strings and the sixth being a number.

```
[s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, values] = textread('/path/xyz.csv', '%s %s %s %s %s %f', 'headerlines', 1);
```

That allows you to get the date (concatenate strings in s1-s3, remove the trailing comma), the time (s4), the name (s5) and the value.